# Why does this blue rectangle align differently in Opera and Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, opera

```
<div style="float:left; width:465px;">xxx</div>
<div style="width:320px; border:1px solid #099aef; position:absolute; display:inline;">Different position of this rectangle in Opera vs Google Chrome</div>
```

Opera displays the blue rectangle to the left, Chrome displays it different. Why?
P.S. The code was significantly simplified to find an error and may have no sense now.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how Chrome is displaying the page differently than Firefox?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VAdNA/

Comment: Chrome displays it to the right: 465px to the right.

Comment: Firefox isn't displaying it to the left for me.

Comment: @Tyilo: better to take normalization off. (http://jsfiddle.net/VAdNA/1/) Also, I see to visible difference between latest FF and Chrome.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.... Chrome and Opera... Sorry for typo (I have several browsers opened)... I was talking about Opera and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Chrome is ignoring your absolute positioning on the second div in the absence of position coordinates.  Instead, it's displaying the second div to the right of the first as if it was in the normal page flow.

Comment: Chrome is not ignoring. You mean Opera is ignoring, right? Chrome is not ignoring, IE6 (IE8+ not tested) and FF are not ignoring.

Comment: No Chrome is ignoring.  If Opera is displaying it to the left, that is correct. Since you didn't specify a top/left position, the position defaults to top:0, left:0.